# android app data not appearing on parse dashboard

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm trying to make a new social app. I went parse.com and made a new app. downloaded the zip file and opened it in the android studio. after that i initialized my keys and compiled the code. It gave no errors and loaded the app on the emulator. Then i added the code to add new user to the database and ran the app. All went ok and log cat didn't give me any errors but when i pressed the test button to check if data got added in the cloud or not but it said "no data yet". yes i did initialize the keys right and my manifest file does include internet permission. Can anyone please tell me whats wrong? I copied all this code from parse

```
public class ParseStarterProjectActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
    user.setUsername("my name");
    user.setPassword("my pass");
    user.setEmail("email@example.com");

    // other fields can be set just like with ParseObject
    user.put("phone", "650-555-0000");

    user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
            } else {
                // Sign up didn't succeed. Look at the ParseException
                // to figure out what went wrong
            }
        }
    });



    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());
}
}
```

Comment: Add some logging code in the `done` method of the `SignUpCallback` and check if it saved the object successfully or not. If you have results from that, update the question with the results.

Comment: this solved it. added it in done

if (e == null) {
                                // Show a simple Toast message upon successful registration
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Successfully Signed up, please log in.",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Sign up Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                        .show();
}